# How to deal with AMD plugins in webpack?

Tags: plugins, webpack, amd

AMD plugins (http://requirejs.org/docs/plugins.html) allow you to load content conditionally.

An example is the text plugin (http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#text):

```
require(["requirejs/text!file.txt"], function(myFile){
          console.log("contents of file.txt: " + myFile);
});
```

How can I configure webpack (webpack.config.js) so I can actually continue to use this pattern in my code? I basically want a bundle where both the contents of file.txt and my application are all bundled in a single file.

Comment: Webpack should support AMD module loading out of the box. Are you running across issues where it isn't working?

Comment: How do I configure webpack so it can resolve that plugin at build-time? Do I need a loader of some sorts? I get it to work without using a plugin (so regular AMD module without the `!`). But not with plugins.

Comment: I have the same problem : `define('json!foo.json')` webpack tries to load the `json` module : `Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'json'`

Comment: @krampstudio For that I use `config.resolveLoader.alias.json = path.resolve(__dirname, "path/to/dummy-loader.js")` and `module.exports = src => src;` in `dummy-loader.js` that solve the issue with the *-loader name and the builtin JSON loader in webpack 4